# Retrieve list of objects from Redis using DateTime filter

Tags: c#, windows, service, redis, stackexchange.redis

I working on a C# project and have following class:

```
public class myObject
{
    DateTime ArrivalTime;
    string Name;
    bool isLocal;
    string UniqueID;
}
```

i want to push instances of above class in Redis based on UniqueID but is it possible to retrieve list of objects based on one or more properties of object e.g.

get all instances on myObject whose ArrivalTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) and ArrivalTime < DateTime.Now

for simplicity sake i am willing to use ArrivalTime as key instead of UniqueID, if that the case how can i retrieve list of objects based on above mentioned filter?

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange.Redis acts as a raw redis client; it does not attempt to provide / automate additional patterns (except a very limited few, such as atomic locking). What you describe simply *is not an inbuilt supported redis operation*. In redis, indexes must be built manually; for example, an index on the `ArrivalTime` might be implemented  using a sorted-set using the `UniqueID` as the *member* and the `ArrivalTime` as the *score*, then `zrangebyscore` and `zrevrangebyscore` to query the data (the method names in SE.Redis are similar, but with a `SortedSet` prefix rather than a `z` prefix). So: *if you additionally index your data manually into a sorted-set*, yes: that's easy.